# Matrix Index Interleaving

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am familiar with matrix indexing in Matlab yet this certain syntax is tripping me up a bit. For example, `a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]` and `b = [2 4 6 8 10 1 3 5 7 9]`. I realize that `a(b)` will just equal matrix b but the issue comes up when I do `a(b) = a`. This syntax produces the matrix `[6 1 7 2 8 3 9 4 10 5]`. I am sure there is a pattern there that I am missing but I have spent too long looking at this to notice it. What exactly is going on here and what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `a(b) = a` is performing a [vectorized indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) operation across the elements of `b` and `a` (requiring them to have the same number of elements, which they do). For a better understanding of what it's doing, here's the equivalent non-vectorized operation done with a for loop:

```
c = a;  % Store original to work from
for index = 1:numel(b)
  a(b(index)) = c(index);
end
```

So, element `a(b(1))` (or `a(2)`, the second element) is assigned the value from `a(1)`, element `a(b(2))` (or `a(4)`, the fourth element) is assigned the value from `a(2)`, etc. It is equivalent to sorting the elements of the index vector `b`, then applying that same sorting permutation to `a`. For the given vector `b`, this places elements from the first half of `a` in the even index positions and elements from the last half of `a` in the odd index positions.